# Sharepoint 2010 - Search is not showing results for users with Read access

Tags: search, search-results

Users with contribute access could search the contents from the SharePoint 2010 List whereas search is not showing any results for the users with Read access?

Users with Read access could see the items on the list however could not search alone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has the content been properly re-indexed after you made your changes?  Depending on your version and environment settings, the new permissions may not take effect in the search results until the content is crawled.

Comment: Just removed the user and added again, it fixed the issue however root cause is unknown..!